# PHP page shows half code from loop in browser

Tags: php, browser

I am having a problem with my php code as it shows half code from loop in the browser after the comparison statement.

```
    <?
include_once("connection.php");
connect_mysql();
$qry="select * from page_content where pg_id='1'";
$res=mysql_query($qry);
if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
{
  $r=mysql_fetch_array($res);
  $txt = $r["pg_text"];
}
?>
```

it shows like this on browser.
[Error on Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieVWw.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Type the following: <?php phpinfo(); ?> in the file. What output do you get?

Comment: Syntax error, php opening tag should be `<?php`, you can't use `<?` without some configurations to allow it

Answer (score 2):

Please add in first line `<?php` not `<?` (because maybe you have not configure short tags using, from php.ini) and you can remove `?>` at ends line, it's a good practice.

Comment: "PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option). " http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Yes I know about that.)